# Go back to a specific activity without starting it again

Tags: java, android, android-intent, stack

'suppose i have activities A,B,C,D.
i start these activities like A->B->C->D
now i want to go back to A on the click of a button without loading its 
data again.
note: i don't want this all on backpress.

i have already tried.'

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

'but the reason is that it start the A again. all the api's calls again.

what i want is that. for example i have two activities like 1,2
and i start them like 1->2
now if i finish 2 on a button click 1 will be shown to me without 
starting it again. i want the same thing from D to A on the click of a 
button not on back press.'

Comment: startactivityforresult() will do

Comment: set launchmode to `singleTop` in `manifest`. And open the same activity and set flags as `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

Comment: @sanjeev basically explicity setting launchmode to anything but multiple will work

Comment: @sanjeev yeah i guess .... :D still better to just tell him everything and let him figure out what suits his needs best, you never know when single top can bite you

Comment: @Kushan true. Sometimes he might want to reload it and might not work and there might be another stack post :P

Comment: Better to use fragments instead of activities (single activity) and navigation component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just a clear top flag causes the target activity to get destroyed first and then recreated. To avoid this, use two flags:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

this will cause the activity to not get finished thus your API call wont happen again. The intent you use here to start the activity A will be delivered to onNewIntent() method in activity A in this case if you need it.

This is all assuming that you have not specified any launch mode in your activity manifest declaration of are using "multiple" launch mode.

As per the docs:

> If it has declared its launch mode to be "multiple" (the default) and you have not set FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP in the same intent, then it will be finished and re-created; for all other launch modes or if FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is set then this Intent will be delivered to the current instance's onNewIntent().